# Partitioned SUM and COUNT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of daily events as follows:

```
EventTypeID INT (multiple events, not unique)
EventDate (cast(EventDate) as Date)
HeadCount INT
```

I need to produce this:

```
EventDate, AvgHeadCountET, AvgHeadCountTotal
```

Where each day I have an average HeadCount per EventType and an average HeadCount for all events that day.

I've done this using #TempTables with a couple of passes, but I can't help but think that there's a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: How do you want to output average count per event type? As one column per event type?

Comment: One row per event date and event type. In other words, GROUP BY EventDate, EventType. Also need to produce this for a single EventType by date, but that's pretty much the same thing only with a where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you need to calculate the average explicitly -- that is, take the sum and divide by the count:

```
SELECT EventDate,EventTypeID,
       AVG(HeadCount) AS AvgHeadCountET,
       (sum(sum(HeadCount)) over (partition by EventDate) /
        count(*) over (partition by EventDate)
       ) as AvgHeadCountTotal
FROM t
GROUP BY EventDate, EventTypeID;
```

Mixing window functions and aggregation functions does result in funky syntax (such as `sum(sum())`, but they do work together.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/214c9/1) is a SQLFiddle illustrating it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
SELECT EventDate,EventTypeID
     , AVG(HeadCount) AS AvgHeadCountET
     --, AVG(AVG(HeadCount)) OVER (PARTITION BY EventDate) AS AvgHeadCountTotal 
     , SUM(SUM(HeadCount)) OVER (PARTITION BY EventDate)/COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY EventDate) AS AvgHeadCountTotal 
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY EventDate,EventTypeID
```

The `AVGHeadCountTotal` value will be repeated across records for each EventDate in the above.

Comment: I get an error message: HeadCount is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: This runs, but produces wrong results. I don't think averaging averages works in general. I did try it though, wrong results.

Comment: It produced the proper result on my sample, but I was only grouping by one field... it does get ugly, instead should calculate average via count and sum I think.... updated for another try.